# What's the best way to test an application built in Sinatra and Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, rspec, sinatra, bdd, jasmine

I'm new to Sinatra and Backbone. I've done testing for Rails using Rspec and Cucumber. I'm wondering the smartest way to approach testing an application built in Sinatra and Backbone.js.

I was thinking of using Rspec to test some of the logic in Sinatra and then using Jasmine to test the Backbone portion. Then I was also going to use Cucumber to do integration testing.

Is this overkill? Could one cancel the other out and render it not useful? Could Jasmine replace Rspec altogether?

I should also mention that the Sinatra app communicates with an API exposed by a separate Rails app. Maybe there is a smart way to mock/model that data to run tests on as well.

Thanks!

Comment: this is probably a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ but Rspec and Jasmine are fine for unit testing with Cucumber for integration (I use all three, but prefer angular to backbone), careful of analysis paralysis :) you can always swap in/out testing frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar position, in that I use Sinatra mainly for writing data API's and now write web apps using Backbone (or whatever). Since you have a data API, I'd test the API using RSpec and Rack Test, which will probably the nicer part of your day. The rest of the week you could use any of the javascript testing frameworks (Jasmine, Sinon etc…) to test the Backbone portion, and hope to get back to using Ruby as soon as possible! ;) It's up to you whether you mock the calls to the data API, or just run them against it, I think the main factor in making that choice would be speed.

I don't think it's overkill to use both, since you have a separate API it should have it's own specs, as other clients may start connecting to it too. It's also a hell of a lot easier to spec an HTTP call than whatever else the Backbone app is doing + an HTTP call.

I don't use Cucumber personally, it seems superfluous if you have the other specs, but YMMV.